# Fuelphp : Knowing the name of the current route

Tags: fuelphp

I have named all my routes. Is there any way to know the name of the route that was selected for the current request?

`'a/b/(:segment)/(:segment)' => array('a/b/$2/index/$1', 'name' => 'test'),`

The Route object does not seem to contain that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added to 1.8/develop, and will be part of the 1.7.2 release:  https://github.com/fuel/core/commit/30ba478c040efc41907c13e6e9402d824fa87242

Next time, use the FuelPHP forum, IRC, or issue a feature request. You'll get a faster response.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you can't get the name of the active route at this time. Looking at the code it seems the `Route` object is not aware of its name, but rather the `Router` indexes named routes by the name. And given that you do not have the `Route` object that is being used for the request it does not seem like it would be possible to extract that information easily.

Comment: After much banging my head into the wall, I pretty much arrived at the same conclusion. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry there's not a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful.

```
$active = Request::active();
echo $active->route->name;
```